# ASP.NET MVC C# set model property values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having some problems with setting the values for my `summaryVm` in the controller method. I am accepting an `OrderVM` and I have checked in debug mode and the properties of `OrderVM` are all set when it is passed and the `Order` also had all values set (including `orderID`). However later in the method when I try to set the values of my `SummaryVm` to these values the `summaryVm.Tickets` is `null`, as is the `summaryVm.orderID`. Yet `email` and `eventID` are being set fine.

If anyone has suggestions on what I'm doing wrong it would be great because I'm at a loss to see what's wrong.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)

        return View("CreateOrder", model);
    }

    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
    Event currentEvent = db.Events.Find(model.EventID);

    Order order = new Order
    {
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        EventID = model.EventID,
        Event = currentEvent,
        user = currentUser

    };
    float total = 0;

    // Initialise a TicketsOrdered data model for each valid ticket
    foreach (TicketVm ticket in model.Tickets.Where(t => t.Quantity > 0))
    {
        total += (ticket.Price*ticket.Quantity);
        TicketsOrdered ticketOrder = new TicketsOrdered
        {
            OrderID = order.OrderID,
            TicketID = ticket.TicketID,
            Quantity = ticket.Quantity
        };
        db.ticketsOrdered.Add(ticketOrder);
    }

    order.OrderTotal = total;
    currentEvent.Order.Add(order);
    currentUser.Order.Add(order);


    SummaryVm summaryVm = new SummaryVm
    { 
        email = order.user.UserName, 
        orderID = order.OrderID,
        tickets = model.Tickets, 
        totalPrice = total, 
        eventID=model.EventID,
        stripePublishableKey=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stripePublishableKey"]
    };

    db.Orders.Add(order);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("OrderSummary", "Order", summaryVm);
}

public class OrderVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    // additional properties of Event you want to display
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // additional properties of Order and OrderDetails you want to edit
    public IList<TicketVm> Tickets { get; set; }
    public Event events {get; set;}
}

public class SummaryVm
{

    public IList<TicketVm> tickets { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public float totalPrice { get; set; }
    public int orderID { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public string stripePublishableKey { get; set; }
    public string StripeToken { get; set; }
    public string StripeEmail {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: You must instantiate your SummaryVm after db.SaveChanges() line.
By doing that Order.OrderID will not be null. Anyway I don't know why Tickets are null. If it was null then your foreach loop must failed at NullReferenceException.

Comment: Thank you! @CodeNotFound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move **SaveChanges** before creating **SummaryVm**

```
...
db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges(); 

SummaryVm summaryVm = new SummaryVm
{ 
    email = order.user.UserName, 
    orderID = order.OrderID,
    tickets = model.Tickets, 
    totalPrice = total, 
    eventID=model.EventID,
         stripePublishableKey=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stripePublishableKey"]
};

return RedirectToAction("OrderSummary", "Order", summaryVm);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why the tickets aren't being set? the var total is being assigned a value so model.Tickets definitely contains at least 1 ticketVm. Therefore I don't know why summaryVm.tickets= model.Tickets isn't working!

Comment: If your total > 0, then indeed there're tickets. Can you provide SummaryVm and OrderVm class definitions?

Comment: I have edited my question to include these viewmodels thanks!

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your classes. Can you access your code in debug mode? If yes, when you are checking Tickets property from model, does it contain any data? After creating summeryVM did you check in debug that there is no data in tickets prop?

Comment: yes I enter debug and my model contains two ticketVm which both contain data. Then the summaryVm tickets property contains the two two ticketVm, both with data. When I try to display them in my view or use them in my next method they don't appear to be accessible

Comment: For passing complex data from one action to another, you should use TempData or Session.